# After redirect session lost in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

The session value lost after the redirect. I m redirecting from pay_order method to do_payment method. when I print the session value in do_payment method its return false. just simple calling the do_payment method display the session value. Please help what is the problem with redirect..?

```
function pay_order($order_id)

{
                 $this->load->helper('url'); //loading url helper    
                 $this->load->library('session');//loading session lib
                 $this->load->library('cart'); //loading cart lib
                 $this->load->helper('form');//loading form helper
                 $output = $this->cart->contents();// getting data from cart.
                 $output = $this->sort_array($output);// sorting the array
                 $list['data'] = $output;
                 $list['order_id'] = $order_id;
                 $this->session->set_userdata('abc', $list);// setting the session
                 redirect('checkout/do_payment'); // redirecting to do_payment

    }
    function do_payment() 
    {

             $this->load->helper('url'); //loading url helper
             $this->load->library('session'); //loading session library
             $arr = $this->session->userdata('abc');// getting session data in $arr
             var_dump( $arr );// return false value.
             //$this->load->view('order/pay_through_gateway');
    }
```

when I redirect from pay_order method the session is not available in do_payment method. why?

Comment: Yes to what Ritesh pointed out. And - you are putting the cart contents into the session?

Comment: Yes I am putting cart items in session. ? but not able to get all those after redirection.

Comment: @MuhammadDanish
on method `do_payment` show the session like this `print_r($this->session->userdata);` and show us the results

Comment: codeigniter creates and maintains a session for the cart items. you have to set up a db session table. take a look at the manual: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html

Comment: I know that codeigniter save the cart data in session. with session data i am also adding some other info and saving in session.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem, check the line in the method `pay_order()` where you are setting the session.

```
$list['order_id'] = $order_id
$this->session->set_userdata('abc', $list);// setting the session
```

Before that line you have missed semicolon. And everything looks fine.

**Update:**

There is no error as I think, check whether you may have null value while you are storing the values in session. And check the values by following code in `do_payment()` method.

```
function do_payment(){
    $this->load->library('session'); //loading session library
    $arr = $this->session->userdata('abc');// getting session data in $arr
    print_r( $arr );// print the $arr content
}
```

Comment: Ritesh I am not missing the semicolon. mistakenly removed by me during asking question.

Comment: The code is working fine now. I have clear the browser data. may be due to cookies confilict this was happening. But when I use session_data as the name of session object. It again not store the session.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$list['order_id'] = $order_id
```

To this:

```
$list['order_id'] = $order_id;
```

You have a semicolon missing. You do not see any errors because of the redirection.

Comment: I am not missing semicolon. mistakenly removed by me during asking question.